# jquery ui resizable - prevent overlap

Tags: jquery-ui, overlap, resizable

I have multiple divs with absolute positioning on a page, all with the same class.
Is there a way to restrict resizing each of the divs so that they do not overlap any of the other divs of the same class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the resize event from jQuery-ui resizable. Calculate if your element is about to pass another elements top/left positions and prevent it from doing so by setting the maxWidth to it's current width.

Source:
[Prevent jQuery UI resizable element from covering another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070550/prevent-jquery-ui-resizable-element-from-covering-another-element)